# Проблема с датой

Tags: php, дата

Функция отрабатывает и показывает что сейчас 12-ое число, хотя уже 13.Это из за часового пояса? Если да подскажите как исправить!

```
echo date('j', time());
```

Comment: Какая функция? Приведите пример используемой функции.

Comment: Обычная функция date,изменил вопрос!

Comment: Если нужно глобально изменить часовой пояс можете использовать функцию [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).  А так да, по умолчанию используется *UTC*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы точно узнать, какая разница между вашим временем и временем сервера, можно сделать так:

```
echo date('P');
```

Это покажет разницу с UTC. Например, если там будет `+00:00`, то на сервере установлена часовая зона, совпадающая с UTC. Это просто как шпаргалка на будущее, если очень быстро нужно узнать текущее смещение, без того, чтобы вызывать `date_default_timezone_get()` и потом искать в интернетах смещение в часах, соответствующее названию этой часовой зоны.

Чтобы установить собственную таймзону, нужно выполнить:

```
date_default_timezone_set('идентификатор таймзоны');
```

Чтобы не лазать в поисках, как правильно называется ваша таймзона, можно сделать так:

```
date_default_timezone_set(timezone_name_from_abbr('', 3*3600));
```

Команда `timezone_name_from_abbr('', 3*3600)` указывает, что нужно найти название таймзоны, смещение которой в секундах равно `3*3600` — плюс три часа. Если нужно плюс четыре часа, то будет `4*3600`. Если плюс три с половиной часа — `3.5*3600` и т.д.

После этого, чтобы удостовериться, что таймзона установилась правильная, можно опять выполнить:

```
echo date('P');
```

Если показалось правильное смещение, то всё в порядке и теперь можно будет использовать `date('j')` без опасения, что будет показываться неправильное число.

Команда `date_default_timezone_set(timezone_name_from_abbr('', 3*3600));` вызывается один раз в начале работы скрипта (уточняю на всякий случай). Перед каждым вызовом `date` её не нужно устанавливать.

Но самый правильный способ — один раз установить в php.ini правильную таймзону (параметр `date.timezone`) — это избавит от нужды в каждом скрипте выполнять `date_default_timezone_set`.

Comment: Спасибо большое попробую

Comment: Проверил вашей функцией у меня +1, это получается что разница c UTC у меня на данный момент 1 час?

Comment: Поэтому и дату показывал12-ое число,то есть 13-ое наступило бы через час.Это мне сейчас надо задать часовой пояс моей страны?

Comment: @quaresma89 Сорри, я не знаю, какой вам нужно задать часовой пояс. Но, зато, я в ответе сразу написал, как это делать. Вам остаётся только нужное смещение вписать в моём примере и всё. Если мой первоначальный ответ был не до конца понятен, пожалуйста, скажите, что именно вызывает затруднения, и я попробую его переписать попроще.

Comment: Нее как раз все очень понятно объяснили,я во всем разобрался.Просто вот единственный момент если можно поясните.Сервер находится в Молдавии,в настройках я смотрел задан   часовой пояс +2, то есть Europe/Chisinau.Допустим человек заходит на сайт с другой страны,какое время ему будет показывать,время сервера?

Comment: @quaresma89 да, время сервера. Чтобы показывать пользователю его локальное время нужно либо использовать geoip для вычисления его местоположения, либо делать трюки с JavaScript, который будет отправлять на сервер сдвиг временной зоны из пользовательского браузера. Это целый программный комплекс получается. Я вряд ли могу в комментариях описать.

Comment: Ну уже буду сам разбираться,спасибо ща советы